# how to say that this question or issue is understood by me and I am good now?

Tags: indian-english

If someone asks for particular issue pointing to me:

> do you want add some thing,  is it understood

then how to reply with a good short sentence? Or what is the best way to say

> yes, it is understood by me and I am now good for this issue or questions

(analyst speaking over call)?

Answer (score 1):

In casual American English, we like to say "Got it" to mean, I understand, go ahead.

Comment: thanks , after that my team member asks me is there any question on this point  then how to reply?  is it good to say :  i am good now for this question

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially (in every day language) we say something like, "O.K./okay," "alright," "got it," or "sure/sure thing."

Answer (score 0):

If someone asks "do you want to add something?" but you don't you can say:

"No, I'm good."
"Sounds good to me."
"No, I'll buy [into] that."

Answer (score 0):

Seeing some clues in your question, I assume a few things:

(a) Your discussion is technical, and it may have several topics/issues/problems, one after another.
(b) You do this over a phone call.
(c) You're not comfortable with saying complicated sentences in English, especially when you want to make your points clear.

Basically, I assume that you're in my shoes when I started working abroad.
(Yes, I'm a non-native speaker.)

If someone asked me, *"Is there any question? Would you like to add anything?"* to conclude one of the topics/issues/problems, and I were in your shoes (i.e., (a), (b), and (c) are true), I might reply:

> (No.) It's good/okay (now). (Let's move on (to the next topic/issue/problem).)

<sup>The parenthesized parts can be omitted. The slashes (i.e., those / signs) indicate possible alternatives. (So, you have about 2*2*2*(1+(1+3)) = 40 alternatives. ;-) I think it's likeliest that I'd reply *"It's good now. Let's move on."* or maybe *"It's good now. Let's move on to the next issue."* when I think just *move on* may not be clear enough, to the listener(s).</sup>

This is clear and concise and easy to pronounce, in my opinion.
Hope it can help you a little. :-)

Comment: You are right , i am developer , i have to attend Skype call with US team , always  listening all these questions ,so want good ans so i can make good conversation.

Comment: Note that if you're not the decision maker or part of the decision making group in the team, you may not want to use *"Let's move on"*, which sounds more like something a team/project leader might say. Even just *"It's good/okay now"* can imply that you're in control of the conversation. If you're not in that position, shifting it from *"It's good/okay now"* to *"I'm fine/okay with it"* would be a better choice.

Comment: ya got it some times i have to become host of the meeting , so at that time i can use this .